# Is there any situation where bloodletting should be paired with transfusion?

Tags: hematology, medicine

Clearly, bloodletting only has benefits in a couple of rare instances —— for example promoting blood flow into reattached tissues<sup>1</sup>. But could it (or, should it) realistically be used along with transfusion for any purpose? Why or why not? (Based on Bradbury's Fahrenheit 451, where it mentions a blood transfusion/removal device)

1: [Bennett-Marsden, M., & Ng, A. (2014). Hirudotherapy: a guide to using leeches to drain blood from tissue. Clinical pharmacist, 6.](https://www.pharmaceutical-journal.com/publications/previous-issues/cp-june-2014/hirudotherapy-a-guide-to-using-leeches-to-drain-blood-from-tissue/11136626.article?firstPass=false)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This site tends to very exacting, so I would recommend you avoid statements like "bloodletting has been disproved", when you are really talking about its medical benefits. We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: I've made some edits that I hope will make this more acceptable to this community, but your question may actually belong on the [medicalsciences.se] site ...